# Does the degree of freedom change with speed for massive particle?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, field-theory, degrees-of-freedom

There are 2 degrees of freedom for a photon. But how many are there for massive particles and will this change with speed?

Answer (score 2):

The number of degrees of freedom (dof) does not change with speed.

1. Massless particles with helicity $h$ all have 2 dof if $h\neq0$ and 1 dof if $h=0$. A photon has $h=1$ and has 2 dof.
2. Massive particles with spin $j$ have $2j+1$ dof. A massive gauge boson has $j=1$ and has $3$ dof.

PS - *Mass also does not change with speed!*

Comment: What do you mean by a "massive photon"?